# rm No such file or directory

Tags: filesystems

I don't understand what happened here:

```
# ls -la
ls: cannot access '1181781909'$'\016''2844_1.fresh:2,': No such file or directory
total 124
drwx------ 2 s2 s2 122880 Jan 31 20:57  .
drwx------ 3 s2 s2   4096 Jan 31 20:57  ..
-????????? ? ?  ?       ?            ? '1181781909'$'\016''2844_1.fresh:2,'
# rm 1181781909^N2844_1.fresh\:2\, 
rm: cannot remove '1181781909'$'\016''2844_1.fresh:2,': No such file or directory
#
```

The file is there, but it has no permissions, no size, and rm can not stat it.
What caused this and how do I get rid of this file?

Edit:
I tried to unmount the filesystem and fsck it, but still same result:

```
# fsck /dev/sdb1 
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sdb1: clean, 50903473/61054976 files, 167306276/244190390 blocks
# mount ...
# cd ....
# ls -la
ls: cannot access '1181781909'$'\016''2844_1.fresh:2,': No such file or directory
total 124
drwx------ 2 s2 s2 122880 Jan 31 20:57  .
drwx------ 3 s2 s2   4096 Jan 31 20:57  ..
-????????? ? ?  ?       ?            ? '1181781909'$'\016''2844_1.fresh:2,'
#
```

Edit 2:
This is an usb drive, and I can not see any obvious errors in `dmesg`. I tried `umount`ing it, then unplugging it, and replugging it. All seems fine, but the file is still there and I can not `rm` it:

```
[1228890.560683] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[1228890.581493] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0480, idProduct=a200
[1228890.581498] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[1228890.581502] usb 2-2: Product: External USB 3.0
[1228890.581506] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
[1228890.581509] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 20170219005804F
[1228890.582340] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[1228890.582679] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[1228891.602341] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  External USB 3.0 0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[1228891.603059] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[1228894.192062] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[1228894.192283] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[1228894.192288] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[1228894.192501] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[1228894.202195]  sdb: sdb1
[1228894.203659] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[1228895.097777] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Edit 3:
The fsck I did missed the `-f` flag. `fsck -f` solved the problem:

```
# fsck -f /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 1594688 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 10620301 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 37521525 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 38541378 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 38541380 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 53190555 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes
Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Problem in HTREE directory inode 43408878: block #10 has bad max hash
Invalid HTREE directory inode 43408878 (x).  Clear HTree index<y>? yes
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 3A: Optimizing directories
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/sdb1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sdb1: 50903473/61054976 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 167306211/244190390 blocks
#
```

Comment: There might a problem with your harddrive, underlying file system and/or kernel module and such. Check `dmesg` for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a file system with errors. It can be caused by:

- RAM errors (unlikely, highly unlikely if ECC RAM)
- Unflushed disk buffers e.g. by power loss or disconnecting USB before cache is flushed (likely)
- Disk errors (fairly likely)
- Errors in the file system code (high unlikely if it is a well tested filesystem)

You should `umount` the file system and run `fsck -f` (to force the fsck even if the system seems clean), `badblocks`, `memtest86`.

Comment: I tried the fsck route, but still same result. I edited the question to include the results.

Comment: @simon you haven't shown that you've run `fsck -f /dev/sdb1`. What you have shown is `fsck` not bothering to check the drive because it "knew" it didn't need checking. That `-f` flag is essential.